# Mapping list of object as secondary tables in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I would like to change this so that TypeEn and TypePl become one class named Type. I dont know how to change this structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="place")
class Place{

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TypePl> typePl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "place", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<TypeEn> typeEn;
}
```

TypePl and TypeEn classes has the same fields:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "place_tag_pl")
public class TagPl implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "place_id")
    private Place place;
}
```

Comment: Have an interface `Type` and let `TypePl` and `TypeEn` be the the implementations of it. You can just put one reference to `Type`  in the class and then your use cases will be fine to be modeled.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this solution, but might exist other resolve this problem  without create interface?